# Extracting date from database and converting to minutes since 0000H

Tags: java

I would like to know how to extract `Date` from my database which is in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format and convert it into minutes in multiple different columns of my program.

An example of my desired output would be `20150421103000` to 630.

Here's a portion of my code:

```
this.setSQL(dataFinder);
ResultSet rs = this.retrieveAllData(handler, tracker);
while ( rs.next() )
{
    if ( rs.getString("dG2") != null )
    {
        fSW.put(rs.getString("dG2").trim().toUpperCase(), new StringWriter());
        DGGSW.put(rs.getString("dG2").trim().toUpperCase(), new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
}

this.setSQL(dataFinder2);
rs = this.retrieveAllData(handler, date);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

List<String> dcph = new ArrayList<String>();

while ( rs.next() )
{
    String leuk= rs.getString("leuk");
    if ( !dcph.contains( leuk) )
        dcph.add(leuk);

    String listOfData = "";

    if ( rs.getString("mou") != null )
        listOfData= rs.getString("mou");

    String[] listedData = listOfData;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <listedData .length ; i ++ )
    {
        if ( DGGSW.containsKey(listedData [i]) )
            DGGSW.get(listedData [i]).put(leuk, + /* method for date time to convert to minutes after 12 */);
    }
}           
for ( int i = 0 ; i < leuk.size(); i++)
{
    stringWriter.append( leuk.get(i)  + ",");

    for ( String listedData : DGGSW.keySet() )
    {
        if ( DGGSW.get(listedData ).containsKey(  myFLNO.get(i)  ) )
            fSW.get(listedData ).append(",");
        else
            fSW.get(listedData ).append("0,");
        }
    }

    String resultString = "," + stringWriter.toString();

    for ( String leukNo: gates.keySet() )
        resultString += leukNo+ "," + fSW.get(leukNo).toString();

    resultString = resultString.replace("," + !!! , " ");

    this.writeToFile(resultString);
}
```

Comment: What is the pattern of the date and time that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know is to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
    import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
    import org.joda.time.Minutes;
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    String datefromDb = "20150421103000"; // would come from your database call
    // create your pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");        

    // parse the db date and set to midnight
    LocalDateTime midnight = dtf.parseDateTime(datefromDb).withHourOfDay(0)
        .withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).toLocalDateTime();

    // parse the db date
    LocalDateTime fromDb = dtf.parseLocalDateTime(datefromDb);  

    // output minutes between the 2 datetime
    System.out.println(Minutes.minutesBetween(midnight, fromDb).getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Calendar and Date class to achieve the minute calculation.

```
    String strDate = "20150421103000";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int totalMinutes = hours*60 + minutes;
    System.out.println(totalMinutes);
```